# Text file needs to be saved as current date and time format

Tags: excel, vba

I have given some inputs in an excel file, once the “Submit” button has been pressed it should create a txt file in the directory specified in FileSavePath(e.x C:\Temp). The file should be named ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt (eg 09072019085633.txt).

```
strFile_Path = "C:\temp\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\temp\ " & Format(Now(), "DDMMMYYYYhhmmss") & ".txt")

strFile_Path = "C:\temp\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\temp\ " & Format(Now(), "DDMMMYYYYhhmmss") & ".txt")
```

I expect once i press the submit button it creates the text file in the destination path in the format `ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt`

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: i have an excel front end having list of drop down options available. i have choose/ given the inputs.My Question is once i press the submit button in my excel, it should create a txt file in the directory specified in FileSavePath(e.x C:\Temp). The file should be named ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt (eg 09072019085633.txt) and import the data in to text

Comment: Still not a question.
What happens when you attempt your approach?

Comment: i'm new to vb macro's, i need a vb macro code that create a text file and copy the data to text file once i press the submit button. the name of the text file should be  ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt (Current datetime).(eg 09072019085633.txt)

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub MakeTextFile()
 Dim fs, a As Object
 Dim dayPre, monthPre, hourPre, minutePre, secondPre As String

 If Day(Date) < 10 Then dayPre = "0"
 If Month(Date) < 10 Then monthPre = "0"
 If Hour(Time) < 10 Then hourPre = "0"
 If Minute(Time) < 10 Then minutePre = "0"
 If Second(Time) < 10 Then secondPre = "0"

 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\" & dayPre & Day(Date) & monthPre & Month(Date) & Year(Date) & hourPre & Hour(Time) & minutePre & Minute(Time) & secondPre & Second(Time) & ".txt", True)
 a.WriteLine ("This is a test.")
 a.Close

 Set a = Nothing
 Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It gives the result as expected.